# Jetpack compose animation bug in light mode

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

Hi I tried to achieve a previous question that I made in SO: [Jetpack compose animate open box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68770558/jetpack-compose-animate-open-box?).

So far I'm almost there but there's a weird bug that I don't understand why's that happening.

I have a text that is animated by **AnimatedVisibility with a fadeIn() as the enter animation**, so far this works but only in dark mode, **when I use light mode this text comes from the bottom screen and goes to the box**. Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFKa3o88SPE

**Expected:** The result in dark mode. Just fadeIn() from inside the box.

**Bug:** Comes from the bottom and sets on the box.

Code to repro. All of this is needed to make this happen:

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun TestExpandHorizontally() {
    var text =
        "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."

    var widthState by remember { mutableStateOf(10.dp) }
    val width by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = widthState,
        tween(
            durationMillis = 800,
            easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
        )
    )

    var heightState by remember { mutableStateOf(10.dp) }
    val height by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = heightState,
        tween(
            delayMillis = 800,
            durationMillis = 800,
            easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
        )
    )

    var textVisibility = remember { MutableTransitionState(false) }

    var textWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var textHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    /***
     * IGNORE THIS COLUMN SECTION.
     * This is needed as a final result, it's the same as below 
     * but is a reference so I can get the width/height of the text and apply
     * to the animation.
     */
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                .padding(20.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(20.dp)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                    .onSizeChanged {
                        textWidth = (it.width.toFloat() / 2.2.toFloat()).toInt()
                        textHeight = (it.height.toFloat() / 2.2.toFloat()).toInt()
                    }
                    ,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif
            )
        }
    }

    /**
     * Here's where the magic happens. Animation is here.
     */
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)) {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .width(width)
                .height(height)
                .background(Color.Gray),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            //This AnimatedVisibility doesn't work and acts like it comes from the bottom instead of just fading in
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visibleState = textVisibility,
                enter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(delayMillis = 1000, durationMillis = 1000))
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(20.dp)
                        .animateContentSize()
                    ,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif
                )
            }
        }

        Button(
            onClick = {
                //Apply width/height of the hidden final result
                widthState += textWidth.dp 
                heightState += textHeight.dp
                textVisibility.targetState = true //Invoke text animation
            }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Blue
            )
        ) {
            Text(text = "Press here", color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works totally fine on my emulator and on my device(but my device doesn't have dark theme so it may be related). So it seems like a bug, [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1253476) to compose issue tracker mentioning your device and android version

Comment: I'll do it ty, btw which emulator and device did you use? @Philip

Comment: emulator pixel 5 api 31, device meizu x8, api 27